# Three.js - Apply anisotropy to a texture in a loaded js model

Tags: json, three.js, textures

I'm loading a *.js model which has a texture. The texture itself is a separate file located in the same directory as the model, so the loader adds this texture to the *.js model.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        var aMesh;
        loader.load("models/mesh.js", function (geometry, materials) {
            aMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[0]);
            scene.add(aMesh);
        });
```

The texture gets blurred when viewed at some angle so I need to apply anisotropy filtering to it.

I can only guess that I need to create a **var Texture**, load the texture into it, apply anisotropy and then add this texture variable to the mesh or to its material[0].

Or can I access the texture in the **aMesh** material directly somehow?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work, untested.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var aMesh;
loader.load("models/mesh.js", function (geometry, materials) {
  var maxAnisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  materials[0].map.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
  aMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[0]);
  scene.add(aMesh);
});
```

If not, you could always override the load function of [the JSONLoader class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js).
Or load the model and texture separately.